# HTML form design useful links and reading

Tags: html, forms, ui-design

I think most of us have seen the following: [image: Form]

I'm currently tasked with converting an existing winform app into a web application. The current system is like the "Your company's app" and it would be nice if I can trim it down and make it more use friendly, sleek and usable.

Can anyone recommend any good books, blogs, tutorials etc and UI design, specifically for web forms.

Thanks

Comment: you might want to try on http://ui.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758) and anything else by Steve Krug.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Web Form Design: Filling in the blanks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933820241). Great form analysis and best practices for web form design.

Comment: I love how StackOverflow enters their own Amazon referral to these links. :P

Comment: I actually don't mind that much either. Just smart thinking/monetization on StackOverflows' part.

Answer (score 0):

This has been reblogged a few times; depending on your content you could try the [Mad Lib](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1007) style.

Another suggestion: steal the idea from what works.  I really love the [Domino's Pizza order form](http://express.dominos.com/order/olo.jsp#selectAddress). They've paginated the process into simple steps. They use large icons for the options, and it actually looks nice.